# Como validar datos repetidos en una tabla pivote

Tags: php, laravel

Trabajo en laravel 5.7;Tengo una tabla pivote entre personas y mascotas (se llama mascotas_personas), los campos de esta tabla relacional son:

```
id
id_persona
id_mascota
```

Necesito que la misma combinación entre persona y mascota nunca se repita, pero no se como hacer la validación

Comment: Cabe la posibilidad de que sea la propia base de datos quien se encargue de que no haya duplicados? Si es asi, como has declaro las tablas? Migraciones o SQL?

Comment: Yo realice las tablas mediante MySQL, pero unicamente arme las tablas y las llaves foraneas, no añadi nada mas, ya que no se como hacerlo, aparte, me gustaria mas trabajatlo mediante codigo

Comment: En ese caso, ¿cual es el nombre del modelo?

Comment: Se llaman Person y Pet

Comment: como dice Francisco, la base de datos se puede encargar de que no haya duplicados. Cuando dices "no sé como hacer la validación", ¿te refieres a validar un http request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no lo quieres hacer a nivel base de datos como lo mencionaron en los comentarios, puedes añadir una validación antes de realizar las operaciones que necesites:

```
$person = Person::find(1);
$pet = Pet::find(5);

if ($person->pets->contains($pet))
{
    return '¡Esta mascota ya es tuya!';
}
else
{
    $person->pets()->save($pet); // o attach() si es una relación: m-m.

    return '¡Tu mascota fue registrada con éxito!'; 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que quieres lo que quieres es evitar repeticion de datos (duplicidad), bueno esto se logra de varias formas, puedes hacerlo desde la `migration` por ejemplo:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('persona_pet', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('person_id')->unsigned()->unique();
            $table->foreign('person_id')->references('id')->on('personas');
            $table->integer('pet_id')->unsigned()->unique();
            $table->foreign('pet_id')->references('id')->on('pets');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

--
Espero te sirva

Comment: Hola, el OP dice que quiere hacerlo por programación (por algún motivo). Aun asi, para evitar que se dupliquen las combinaciones, seria `$table->unique(['person_id', 'pet_id'])` para este caso.